# Could questions we have already voted to delete be greyed out as well?

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

I have already voted to delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905653/how-to-find-large-int-1-infty-frac1-x-ln-xx-left1x2-right-ln2-x) and it is 'highlighted' on the list of questions with delete votes as shown.

[image]

For the sake of our convenience, could questions we have already voted to delete be greyed out as well, so that we don't need to click on the link and learn that we have done so weeks before?